# Handle Conflicting Installation Methods Cuda Nvidia

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

In [Link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions) when it is talking about "Handle Conflicting Installation Methods" 
 how I can know what X.Y would be? I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: "Before installing CUDA, any previously installations that could conflict should be uninstalled. " Followed by detailed instructions . If you installed a previous nvidia driver, remove it, end of story.

Comment: So how I can know the version (X.Y) that I have installed

Comment: You  run `nvcc --version` or you look at the version on the .run file or whatever you used to install. Regardless, you need to remove it before you update. Or you can read the page "/usr/local/cuda-X.Y/bin/uninstall_cuda_X.Y.pl" so the version is listed in the directory name and in the uninstall .pl . `ls /usr/local/cuda*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have cuda installed you can get the version from the directory name or from the name on the uninstall.pl

```
ls /usr/local/cuda*

ls /usr/local/cuda*/bin/uninstall*
```

Will yield "/usr/local/cuda-X.Y/bin/uninstall_cuda_X.Y.pl" where the X.Y you are asking about is in the cuda directory and on the uninstall script (uninstall_cuda.X.Y.pl).

Or you can also

```
nvcc --version
```

Regardless of the version , you need to first uninstall it as directed before you install a new version.